# Dell 2950 Perc 6/i "physical disk" and "Enclosure(Backplane)" under Connector 1 in OMSA tree- Troubleshoot help

Tags: hard-drive, perc6, dell-openmanage

Just looking for someone who might know why this could occur...

In OMSA, on my Dell 2950, there usually is only one "Physical Disks" child under "Enclosure (Backplane)" in the tree view.  Currently, the tree looks like this:

Dell PERC 6/i Integrated

Connector 1 (RAID)

- Enclosure (Backplane)

  - Physical Disks (1:04 good, 1:05 removed)
- Physical Disks (1:33 Ready but unused)

Normally it's like this:

Connector 1 (RAID)

- Enclosure (Backplane)

  - Physical Disks (1:04 good, 1:05 good)

From the front, 6 of 6 3.5" SAS drives are connected.  The server is showing Slot 5 as bad and the disk as removed.  It seems that the drive in Slot 5 is being sensed as external to the Enclosure.  Any ideas why this would happen?  Think I can get away with rebuilding the virtual disk by replacing 1:05 with 1:33?

Thanks.

UPDATE:  The only options on the Physical Disk 1:33 were Assign as Global Hot Spare and Clear...

After clearing, I assigned it as the Global Hot Spare.  This allowed the rebuilding of the virtual disk.  Hopefully it won't fail.

I'm still unsure of the reason for this odd behavior.  I'm checking the firmware next.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you remove disk from slot5 (slot0 is the first disk)?

Try to clean inside disk slot, if there is duster.

Try to restart all OMSA related services, if you cannot restart the server(which o.s. is running?).

Comment: I've traded the disk out with 4 different drives.  A quick replacement leads to a rebuild attempt and within 10 minutes a failure.  The server has been rebooted several times and the issue persists.  The Global Hot Spare tactic seems to be holding but I don't want to call off the search just yet.  Slot 5 still shows "removed" and yet the drive in there is working - only it's seen as a different slot (1:33).  The OS is Windows Server 2003 32-bit.  My next task is to upgrade the firmware (it's at 2.10) to 2.37.

Comment: After firmware upgrade, try to enter BIOS RAID setup to check is slot always wrong.